# how to disable filepath in titlebar of a html file

Tags: html

in html when the title is not mentioned

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

then IE automatically shows filepath of html page. How to disable this function.
And No i dont want to put a title element.

Comment: You add a `<title>` element and put in there whatever text you want it to say.

Comment: By writing (real) HTML. The title element is mandatory.

Comment: For what reason can you not add a `<title>` tag?

Comment: @alex i have a textarea where other people will type their html code and the output is shown in a new window. so when the see the output i dont want them to see my file path

Comment: @subanki Do you want to have it hidden for security? If so, there is no point. If people are writing their HTML, shouldn't they be able to add the `title` element themselves. Can you parse the page and add it if it not included?

Comment: @alex nice idea how to parse it if not added ??

Comment: @subanki You may need to ask a new question here for that. I'd pass it with a server side language.

Comment: @subanki If you are not checking your HTML with a server side language before displaying it, you may run into [problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: @alex its ok my files are local so no need to check. and intended to only work in IE

Comment: @subanki What is the purpose of your web app?

Comment: @ alex to only show the correct output of a html codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse the page and add it if it not included as said by alex

Answer (score 2):

use a blank title

```
<title> </title>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<title>Text whtever you want/leave it blank </title>

<head></head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```